# Machine Restarts When Running Visual Studio Load Tests

Tags: c#, .net, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a load test rig, which consists of one controller and 20 agents, when running load test using either VS 2015 or VS 2017 I get the machine restarted and the only error I can get is the one below:

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

(devenv.exe, PID 4964, Thread 43) ControllerProxy: Queue test run error: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.RigExecutionException: Test run 'user@machinename datetime' could not be executed on controller controller. No agents are marked online to execute test run.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerObject.QueueTestRun(TestRun testRun, FileCopyService fileCopyService, IControllerEvents eventHandler)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerExecution.QueueTestRun(TestRun testRun, FileCopyService fileCopyService, IControllerEvents eventHandler)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.QueueTestRunWorker(Object state)

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

However when checking the status of agents in VS I can see all of the agents are online with ready status.

Any idea why I am getting windows restart running VS?
I enabled the logs for test controller and I can't see anything wrong in the logs either.

Comment: Does your user have admin rights on the machine?

Comment: A machine restart is unlikely to be caused by anything specific in the software... rather it's most likely to be a hardware/driver issue on the machine in question. It's a BSOD, and you need to identify the cause of the BSOD, probably by first disabling automatic restarts on system failure.

Comment: @user942620 yes I do, and I run VS as administrator.

Comment: @spender I have the same feeling as well, strangely enough it doesn't happen when running on my PC which is a physical machine not VM as the test controller. I did the disable auto restart option as well but still I get VM restarted even when having the auto restart set to disabled. I was able to identify which test is causing the restart and this is the only test where I have different network simulation set up as in 3G, Dial Up, ...etc.

Comment: @spender is there an easy way for me to trace what caused the system to restart? the quick one I can get is to check event viewer logs. I am not sure if using memory dumb or anything else can lead me to more details. We are using Hypervisor as our virtualization layer to provision create all VMs.